# Los datos no se borran de la base de datos

Tags: java

No consigo que mi aplicación en Java borre datos de una base de datos.

Adjunto código de mi método para borrar:

```
int rowIndex = this.tabla.getSelectedRow();

    try{
       String dni = String.valueOf( tabla.getValueAt(rowIndex, 0));
       st = con.createStatement(); 
       int fila = tabla.getSelectedRow();
       int col = tabla.getSelectedColumn();
       System.out.println(fila);
       System.out.println(col);
       String sql = "DELETE FROM clientes where dni="+dni;          

       st.executeUpdate(sql);
       modelo.removeRow(fila);

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos Borrados");

    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al borrar");
    }
```

ese código es llamado desde un botón en su *actionListener*. He probado con *prepareStatement*, y tampoco. No me interesa esta forma, ya que no sé cómo pasarle por parámetro al método el dni sacado de un JTable.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el error que te da?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema es el string del DNI, deberías de ponerlo entre comillas simples

```
 String sql = "DELETE FROM clientes where dni='"+dni+"'";
```

Comment: siiiiiiiiii era eso... gracias joder....

Comment: @scorpions, menos XXXXX y mas cerrar y valorar la pregunta...

Comment: y como se hace eso?? no lo veo

Comment: Añadiendo la respuesta como respuesta del hilo, y cerrándolo. Para que en futuras búsquedas se vea que está cerrado, y así ayudar a la comunidad

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya haya una respuesta admitida como correcta, considero que incluye una mala práctica, así que añado otra.

Deberías utilizar PreparedStament y no concatenar los parámetros de entrada para evitar posibles ataques por inyección de sql.

Así, el código quedaría:

```
try (PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM clientes where dni=?")){
    st.setString(1,dni);
    st.executeUpdate();
}catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al borrar");
}
```